# How to set read timeout on Jsch exec Channel

Tags: jsch

I'm using Jsch with an exec Channel.  I'm able to connect just fine, but I want it to time out if, for some reason, no data comes in after some time and the connection is not closed.  That is, when the remote process hangs.  Through debugging, I can see that Socket.setSoTimeout() is being called with arguments of 2000 and 5000 (repeatedly, as I've tried setting it in multiple places), but the exec just blocks until the connection is closed. Here's the code:

```
    String host = "192.168.99.100"; // docker-machine default
    String user = "docker";
    String command1 = "./junk.sh";
    try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        jsch.addIdentity("C:\\Users\\johnsmith\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\id_rsa"
                //           , "passphrase"
        );

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setConfig(config);


        session.setTimeout(2000);
        session.connect(2000);
        session.setTimeout(2000);

        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect(5000);
        session.setTimeout(5000);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >=0) {
            System.out.println(".");
            System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, read));
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where junk.sh simply does:

```
echo "some text"
sleep 15
echo "all done here"
```

I am expecting an exception about 2 seconds into the read. But it completes normally:

```
Connected
.
some text

.
all done here

DONE
```

How do you configure ChannelExec to do a read timeout?
As an aside:
   Why is it necessary to first set the inputStream to null? `channel.setInputStream(null)`
   If I get the input stream off the channel *before* connecting, I miss the first part, "some text". Why is that?  I would think you would get the InputStream *after* connecting?